# Installed Rasbian, but reboots to install screen?

Tags: raspbian, pi-4

What am I missing? Noob boots, I select the recommended rasbian install. It goes through a several minute process, but then brings me back to the setup/install screen? Only things I can select in menu is help or install....

Comment: Which model of Pi? What power supply? If your just after Raspbian download the image and flash to sd card with Etcher.

Comment: new pi4. generic PS that came with it (adufruit package). But if the pi boots to the noob installer- shouldn't I be past sc card format and PS issues?  That said I'm willing to try creating a rasbian image.... suggested source?

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/ no need to unzip when using Etcher.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to use Raspbian then using NOOBS is only waste of space. Most of us flash Raspbian direct from an image. Download one of the images from [Raspbian Downloads](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/). This will also avoid the problems you have with NOOBS.

Comment: Thanks, bailed on noob and just imaged raspbian as recommended. Worked flawlessly.

Comment: @PaulLowe If the answer help you it would be nice if you could accept it with a click on the tick on its left side. This would finish the question and does not pop up later again. It shows that it has a solution.